# How to distingush between template class and implicit template argument inside class defintion?

Tags: c++, templates, friend, class-template

C++ allows template arguments that refer to template classes, not instances of it. For example the function `fun` below.

At the same time there is a feature by which template arguments can be omitted inside a class definition. For example in the definition of `template<class T> class A`, we can say `A` to imply `A<T>`.

I found a case where both rules potentially can produce an ambiguity. Moreover I cannot solve the ambiguity. Here it is a MWE, in which in the definition of `template<class T> class B` I need to refer to `B` as a template class and not as `B<T>`.

```
template <template<class> class Y, class T>
auto fun(){return Y<T>{};} // fun can be used with a *template* class

template<class T>
struct A{
    friend void f(A a){} //A here is implicitly A<T>, ok 
};

template<class T>
struct B{
    friend void g(B b){
        fun<A, void>(); // here A is a template class, ok
        fun<B, void>(); // error: no matching function for call to 'fun' because the compiler sees B<T>, not B
    } //A here is implicitly A<T>, 
};

int main(){
    A<void> a{};
    B<void> b{};
    g(b);
}
```

(I need to do this because the function `g` is a friend function that I want to define inside the class.)

Clang 3.5 gives the error described above, and GCC 4.9.2 is ok with it. The worst part is that I cannot make additional specifications and resolve the ambiguity.

For example I tried:

```
    fun<struct B, void>();

    fun<template<class> struct B, void>();
```

but still get the same error.

**Is there a way to tell clang (or a problematic compiler) that `B` is not `B<T>` but the template class `B`?**

(I used some C++11 syntax to simplify the example, but the problem iapplies to C++98 as well. Please correct or let me know if I am not using the right naming conventions.)

Comment: It should be an even bigger issue with `template<template<typename> class> void foo(); template<class> void foo();` style overloading... -- Possible disambiguations include using an alias template (possibly after [CWG 1286](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286)), or referring to the template name from the surrounding scope, e.g. `::B` instead of just `B`.

Comment: Btw, each instantiation of the class template `B` contains an *injected-class-name* that refers to the current instantiation. Inside `B`, the name `B` can therefore refer to both, the injected-class-name (i.e. class) and the class template `B` itself.

Comment: The namespace trick worked (code is `fun<mynamespace::B, void>();`). If I understand correctly, the other seems to work too, (code: `fun<BB, void>();`) but requires this line  `template<class TT> using BB = B<TT>;` and if outside the class additionally a predeclaration of `template<class T> class B;`. The namespace seems more noisy. Code works with gcc and clang.

Comment: This is a [known clang bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9551). I kinda like the `B::template B` workaround suggested in the accepted answer of the linked dup.